# Vue.js Loop Input [v-model] updating all form elements not just one

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have form data of:

```
const form = {
   title: null,
   content: null,
   language: {
      en: { title: null, content: null },
      es: { title: null, content: null }
   }
}
```

My Form inputs

```
<v-form ref="formEl" @submit.prevent="validate">
    <div v-if="Object.keys(form.language).length > 0">
                <div v-for="(language, langCode) in form.language" :key="langCode">
    
                  <v-text-field
                      v-model="form.language[langCode].title"
                      :label="$t('form.title')"
                  />
                  <v-textarea
                      v-model="form.language[langCode].content"
                      :label="$t('form.content')"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
</form>
```

Now when I change the input of 1 form input, it updates both to be the same.
I tried placed a KEY on each input field, with the same result. Does anyone have any thoughts or direction on this? Much appreciated.

[image]

```
  const form = ref(lodash.cloneDeep(state.pages.one))

    // GET CONTENT
    useFetch(async () => {
      loading.value = true
      try {
        await dispatch('pages/getOne', route.value.params.id).then((res) => {
          if (res !== false) {
            form.value = lodash.cloneDeep(res)
          }
        })
      } catch(e) {
        $system.log({
          comp: 'AdminPagesEdit', msg: 'useFetch', val: e
        })
      } finally {
        loading.value = false
      }
    })
```

Comment: Mind double-checking with your Vue devtools what is happening there? Also, where is your `form` object defined, in `data`?

Comment: @kissu I have updated my question to include more code. Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: Mind sharing a whole snippet with `template` + `script` part please?

Comment: For me it's working if the `form` is defined in `data`

Comment: @kissu I added this to codepen for easier viewing https://codepen.io/stickypages/pen/XWYmmgb

Comment: @PhilippeUn Which my form is define in the data. Is there an alternate way of doing this, than what I have?

Comment: Just a thought but, try using reactive instead of ref.

Comment: I see you are working with Compostion API. Unfortunately I am not familiar with this yet :-(

Comment: Another idea would be to explicitly set each property instead of using cloneDeep.  I also don't use the Composition API... Feels to much like React ;)

Comment: Yeah I understand, I too like the older route, but figured I best try it out and get comfortable for future versions. ha! I tried reactive, with no success.

Comment: Seems to be with the lodash.cloneDeep() inside the disptach(). if I just manually enter a object, it works fine. Trying to deal with data coming from VueX and you cannot mutate if you just return the "RES".... so will need to figure something out there.

Comment: `console.log(form.language.en === form.language.es)`